# Flutter - Making a web request

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to know if there is a way to format special characters when parsing JSON requests from Flutter. I have tested a http request as such:

```
void curlRequest() async
  {
    String urlRequest = "http://my.web.url/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=my_token&moodlewsrestformat=json&wsfunction=core_user_create_users&users[0][username]=test_user_4&users[0][firstname]=John&users[0][lastname]=Doe&users[0][email]=john.doe@gmail.com&users[0][password]=Johns_Password";

    http.post(urlRequest, headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}).then((response){
        print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
        print("Response body: ${response.body}");
    });
  }
```

I get the following response:

`http://my.web.url/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=my_token&moodlewsrestformat=json&wsfunction=core_user_create_users&users%5B0%5D%5Busername%5D=test_user_4&users%5B0%5D%5Bfirstname%5D=John&users%5B0%5D%5Blastname%5D=Doe&users%5B0%5D%5Bemail%5D=john.doe@gmail.com&users%5B0%5D%5Bpassword%5D=Johns_Password&i=1`

The request was invalid due to special characters being used. How do I make a request so that the special characters are also handled properly?

Comment: Which API you are trying to call POST or GET?

Comment: It's the http package: https://pub.dev/packages/http

Comment: Yes I totally understand the package but you must have type of API which you are calling, I doubt you are trying wrong way to call POST API.

Comment: I'm sending requests to the Moodle API. I have tested the Moodle API and it works fine.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/send-data maybe this can help also try raw string

Comment: @MrRandom I've tried that tutorial. It did not work unfortunately.

Comment: I think I found the problem. The reason why my requests might be rejected is because of the server I am using. I am currently using a free server. Will need to upgrade to a better server before testing again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to a better web hosting service resolved my issue. I was using AeonFree, which was a free web hosting service and had limited access for obvious reasons.

I also switched from the [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http) to using the [dio package](https://pub.dev/packages/dio).

Answer (score 2):

In a http restful request, the `http GET` request must be url encoded, which means that most special characters must be encoded in a way understandable by a webserver.

As such, characters such as the plus sign (+) or the question mark (?) must be replaced by their URL encoded equivalents (%2b for the plus sign and %3F for a question mark for instance) and vice versa for decoding.

Several URL encoders can be found online such as http://www.url-encode-decode.com/

In Dart you can use `Uri.encodeFull()` to encode string and `Uri.encodeComponent()` to encode a string component

Similarly to decode you can use `Uri.decodeFull()` and others

read more about this here [Uri class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri-class.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm a bit new to network programming, so I thought that might have been the issue. Not sure why my request is not working from my Flutter app. If I run the same request in the browser it works as expected.

Comment: Cool no worries, if this answer helped you please Upvote this and accept this answer as well, I will be delighted by that @meeth23

Comment: Unfortunately, I require 15 points to upvote. Will do so when I can actually accept my own answer.